# Do masked expletives take the same special characters or different?

Tags: expletive-pronoun

I often read sentences with masked expletives *(is this term correct?)* just to avoid offensive words being expressed with their full spellings. Though just one letter would convey the word.

My question is, when we use these masked expletives, are they always with the same characters (******) or take different (@#$%).

Also, is there any order like - !@#$ (Shift + 1, 2, 3, 4)? If there's not then I observe that exclamatory mark does not go well as the first masked expletive!

> Do you think you can bully me? F*** off. 
>   Do you think you can bully me? F#$% off. 
>   Do you think you can bully me? F### off. 
>   Do you think you can bully me? F!@# off - see, (!) does not *look smooth* as the first masked expletive!

Comment: Ben Zimmer calls these **obscenicons**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different variations. Most common are **quimps**, **jarns**, **nittles**, and **grawlixes**.

*Quimps* are mostly astrological symbols, *jarns* are usually different types of spirals, *nittles* are bursting stars, and *grawlixes* are squiggly lines or a string of typographical symbols (@#$%&!), that are used to mask offensive words. Naturally, they can all be mixed and matched according to the level of profanity a cartoonist wants.

Read [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lexicon_of_Comicana) for more info.

As for the order, it is random. There is no special order in which you need to use those characters. There are also no limitations on which character you can use. (but it is true that an exclamation(!) mark in front seems strange)

See [here](http://www.statoids.com/comicana/grawlist.html) for examples on how they were first used. As you notice, most of the time they don't even use characters, but drawings instead.

For internet usage, you will see that most forums and chat rooms will use the asterisk (*) to censor words. Symbols and shapes are mostly used in comics.